# How do I fix the ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement for uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8?

Tags: python, pypi, decompiler

I have downloaded the uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8 egg file from pypi.org website in order to decompile a .pyc file. When I am trying to install it using the pip command in command prompt `pip install uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8 (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8
```

I am using the latest version of Python (3.8). I tried to download another uncompyle file for the earlier 3.7 version, but even then I get the same error. I have also upgraded pip to its latest version. On their website it is mentioned that for Python 3.7 and above, the code in decompyle3 is generally better, yet I get the same error for pycdc.

How could I fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you tried ```pip install uncompyle6```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install .whl files with pip, not .egg. In order to install .egg file you need easy_install.
Try this command:

```
python -m easy_install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/91/07f46d34bf8d3bf385785b98b13ebddaa414638f553d9b33c8aa320f45cd/uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8.egg
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have downloaded a .whl version instead and now it's working.

Comment: @Adriana glad to be of help :)